# Azure authentication with oAuth and tokens

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-mobile-services

I am an azure user and I am using the mobileservice client to generate azure tokens from oAuth provider tokens.

I want to let users securely read/write to MY API, and it appears that the only unique identifier that it gives me is an integer userID. The token, a more difficult to guess string, appears to change every time I generate an unauthenticated client.

What is the best practice for doing this? Could someone just open a client with my appkey, guess the 25 character user ID, and then call my api?

How can I use the token to provide secure read/write to my api? Or is using the User ID,https, obfuscation, etc my best bet? Maybe i could use a tutorial on how tokens work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two or three pieces here.

1) The OAuth provider (Facebook, Google, etc.) is likely providing you a cryptographically signed JSON Web Token (JWT) - secure and trusted
2) The ZUMO token is likewise a JWT - cryptographically signed and can be trusted.
3) You can convert the JWT to the claims that are backing the JWT by called getIdentity() (node.js server SDK) or GetIdentityAsync<> (ASP.NET server SDK)

You can find some information on my blog: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/ - I'm right in the middle of discussing authentication for Azure Mobile Apps.

Comment: Thank you. Your blog is well written and it will be very nice to use as a resource. If you have time to answer, I would like to ask you a question or two to save myself any headaches...

Comment: Basic question from me, but what do you mean by "claims that are backing the JWT"? Does this simply mean that I should be using value returned by getIdentity() on my server to get the unique token that I want?

Comment: When an identity provider returns the token, it is generally formatted as a JWT - Json Web Token (see jwt.io) - in it are specific claims - things like "this users email address is X" - defined as a JSON blob.  You can see what the service will return in the GetIdentityAsync<>() call by reviewing the information in /.auth/me after authenticating (the URL is relative to your azure service)